# Should an interface extending another interface specify overrides?

Tags: java

Or in particular: What is the difference between

```java
interface A {
   void fa();
}
    
interface B extends A {
   void fa();

   void fb();
}
```

and

```java
interface A {
   void fa();
}
    
interface B extends A {
   @Override
   void fa();

   void fb();
}
```

Does it effect the implementing class in any way?

Comment: `@Override` doesn't affect anything. It's a compiler hint. You shouldn't need to define `fa` at all

Comment: What about the good practises? Would it be helpful of me to add the `@Override` anyway, just to make it obvious that there are more methods that are passed from the parent? I'm curious because that's the kind of annotation IDE generates automatically, so maybe there's some reason behind it.

Comment: I personally think it's good practice, but that's just my opinion. External tooling like Checkstyle or sonarqube can enforce you to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it should not. The class that implements `interface B` will still have to provide an implementation of `void fa();` regardless whether interface B annotates the same method signature with `@Override` or not. Also, putting the `@Override` annotation in interface B doesn't make a lot of sense in this case because the annotation basically means that you are overriding the *implementation* that the super class gave to that method signature. Since `Interface A` nor `Interface B` provides an implementation to `void fa()` it doesen't make sense.

It would make sense if `interface A` provided a default implementation to `void fa()` For example:

```
interface A {
   public default void fa(){
     System.out.println("My default implementation");
   }
}
```

In this case Interface B would be overriding the implementation given to `fa()` from Interface A by making it abstract again. The same goes when Interface A defines `fa()` as abstract and Interface B gives it an implementation by turning it into a `default` method.

Answer (score 1):

The @Override annotation is just a reminder to the compiler to show you an error if you define something wrong. It doesn't affect anything. The good practise is to write it always.

Answer (score 0):

Adding or omitting `@Override` doesn't change the overriding behaviour of the `fa` method. It's an override based on the name and parameter types (in this case none), nothing else. The return type needs to be compatible (covariant return), but is not part of the "is this an override or not" decision.

The `@Override` annotation is (mostly) used to verify that a method is overriding a method from a super type. If you omit it, there may be a warning from your IDE or other tooling like SonarQube, but the compiler doesn't care. If you add it incorrectly, that's when its true purpose kicks in - you'll get a compiler error.